Flutter Web not Showing error Message Correctly
This is my Flutter app.
void main() {
  Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
    throw "boom";
  });
  runApp(MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("Hello")))));
}

This does not show "boom" nor the correct log trace. Debugging is now a hell.
errors.dart:296 Uncaught (in promise) Error
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (errors.dart:296:3)
    at main.dart:643:5
    at future.dart:423:39
    at internalCallback (isolate_helper.dart:48:11)
throw_ @ errors.dart:296
(anonymous) @ main.dart:643
(anonymous) @ future.dart:423
internalCallback @ isolate_helper.dart:48
Promise.then (async)

What is the latest Flutter Version that does not have this issue? I cannot downgrade too much.
My current version is:
 Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on macOS 14.0 23A344 darwin-arm64, locale en-US)

I know there is a open Github issue for it, but as a general question, when this kind of blocker issue happen, how to quickly and efficiently make informed decision on which most recent past version to downgrade to ?

I have tried the same code (with 3.22.2) and got the exception: "Unhandled Exception: boom". Nothing is wrong with the code or flutter version. Try to reinstall flutter, just remove the flutter folder and download and extract at same location.

Many people face it https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/150352

@Aks this issue happens on Flutter Web

sorry my bad. I tried to run it in ios. BTW, in web my error is different as yours.

it's saying there's an error inside main.dart but "boom" is not printing

Yep, you've reproduced the issue.

Try the below answer once.

Try this:
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  // Run the app inside a custom Zone to catch asynchronous errors
  runZonedGuarded(() {
    runApp(MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("Hello")))));

    Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () {
      throw "TEST: boom";
    });
  }, (error, stackTrace) {
    // Print the error
    print('Caught by zone: $error');
  });
}

//Also, you can throw error below or above the runApp;
